# Is it necessary to give name to access group in keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keychain

I know that it is necessary to give name to access group in keychain when we want to share some data between two apps.

But I don't have any clear idea whether it is still important to name access group if my app does not share any data with other app?

If I does not name access group, will be there any problem in future?

And all the apps which does not give access group name are stored in same place in keychain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I does not name access group, will be there any problem in future?

No, there wouldn't be a problem. However, you may want to prepare your keychain data for sharing with other versions of your own app. One example is if you decide to offer a "light" and a "pro" version of the same app: users would purchase the "light" version or get it as a free download, and then upgrade to a more expensive "pro" version. If you want the "pro" version to be able to access keychain entries created by the "light" version, add an access group shared by both your apps.

> And all the apps which does not give access group name are stored in same place in keychain?

If you would like to know if keychain entries of apps that do not specify access groups are available to all these apps, the answer is "no". Entries that do not have an access groups specified are private. They are visible to your app, so no other apps could read or modify them.